# How to record Google Hangout Meeting using Vonage(earlier nexmo) APIs?

Tags: opentok, video-recording, tokbox, google-hangouts, vonage

I am trying to find API which can record google hangout meeting in Vonage API documents. But unfortunately I have not been able to find it. Does Vonage provide such functionality? Can anyone redirect me to specific API documentation I can refer to. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Vonage Video API doesn't provide the ability to record a Google Hangout. Google Meet does have recording capability built-in, however. Please see [their documentation](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/9308681?hl=en) for this.